# Is there an abandoned Soviet airport near Luhansk?

Tags: historical-context, ukrainian-language, voroshilovgrad, serhiy-zhadan

In *Voroshilovgrad*, Ernst Thalmann lives at an abandoned Soviet airport that he's trying to resurrect. I'm a little unclear about the exact location of this in the book, but I would assume that it's supposed to be somewhere around Luhansk.

Is the airport referred to in the book a real place, or is it fictional? All I've been able to find is the Luhansk International Airport, which was actually operational until 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the [Staryy Aerodrom](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Staryy+Aerodrom+%22Vovchans%CA%B9k%22/@50.3070682,36.9217494,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x93580b9d7fc5db9d!8m2!3d50.3070611!4d36.921757) near [Vovchansk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vovchansk), in the north of Ukraine very near the Russian border.

It's in the Kharkiv oblast of Ukraine, but on the eastern side of that, relatively near the Luhansk oblast. It used to be the site of an important [Soviet aviation academy](https://ukraine-kiev-tour.com/vovchansk-airfield.html) and is now full of abandoned and decaying aircraft and helicopters.

There's a [video online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCObElz4Y-c) from a lady who went there in 2021. She reaches the airport at around 7 minutes into the video; you can watch her climbing into wrecked aircraft while exploring what seems to be a completely deserted area, before visiting the site of the aviation academy. That's about the most information I can find about it on the English-speaking internet, although there might be more available for those able to search in Russian.